# What is the best way to include comments in chef role?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want to include comments in a chef role.

```
{
    "name" : "custom_chef_role",
    "json_class" : "Chef::Role",
    "default_attributes" : {},
    "override_attributes" : {
        "role_consul" : {
            "cluster" : {

                /* Adding environment name */
                "name" : "cybsnonprod",
    }
    },
    "chef_type" : "role",
    "run_list" : [
    ],
    "env_run_lists" : {}
}
```

Please let me if it is correct to include the comments as below:

```
  /* Adding environment name */
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using JSON files for roles and not the [Ruby DSL](https://docs.chef.io/roles.html#ruby-dsl)?

Comment: @StephenKing - you don't use Ruby for environment-specific data

Comment: Commenting is a legitimate requirement, I occasionally need to add comments myself when builds get broken.

Answer (score 2):

Comments are not normally supported in JSON but the JSON library Chef happens to use does support them using the syntax you show. This may break some ancillary tools that load JSON objects using other libraries though, so caveat emptor.